# Positioning a view under two views (or the lowest view)

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I have a `RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` on the left and then a `TextView` on the right. The `TextView` is downloaded from a website through their API so it's contents will be different each time.

I want to have another `TextView` underneath these two but I am having a problem when the `TextView` length is less than the `ImageView`. When this happens, the `TextView` at the bottom will overlap the `ImageView` because I align the bottom `TextView` to be below the `TextView` on the top right.

What I need to happen is to be able to align the bottom `TextView` under whichever view is the lowest.

This is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/id_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemContentsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemImageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Sample contents\nSample contents\nSample contents" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemIdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemContentsTextView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="1234" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create `LinearLayout` as top parent and make it `orientation:vertical`. Then first add your `relativeLayout` and then add your `TextView`.

So it will looke like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout    
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/id_image" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemContentsTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemImageView"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Sample contents\nSample contents\nSample contents" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemIdTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="1234" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the top `ImageView` and `TextView` in another `RelativeLayout` and use that as anchor for your bottom `TextView`.

Something like this (not tested):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrappingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/id_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemContentsTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemImageView"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Sample contents\nSample contents\nSample contents" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemIdTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wrappingLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="1234" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one more `RelativeLayout` i have **Tested and text Never overlaps**

so it Should be :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemContentsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemImageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Sample contents\nSample contents\nSample contents" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemIdTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="1234" />
```